# Python Pandas: divide a Series by a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Series and a Dataframe that share the same index:

```
s = pd.Series([300, 300])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [10,20],
    'B': [20,30]
})
```

When I do `s.div(df)`, I see:

```
     A    B    0    1
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I expect:

```
     A    B
0   30   15
1   15   10
```

`pandas.__version__`: 1.3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rdiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rdiv.html) for divide from right side:

```
df1 = df.rdiv(s, axis=0)
print (df1)
      A     B
0  30.0  15.0
1  15.0  10.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why pandas doesn't allow a simple Series / Dataframe which is more natural.